# Visual C++ inline assembly char*

Tags: visual-c++, assembly

I need to edit a string received from user in C++ code in assembly. I found this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/y8b57x4b(v=vs.80).aspx and according to it my code should work

```
int main ()
{
   char* s;
   s=new char[80];
   cin.getline(s,80);
   __asm
   {
       mov eax, offset s
   }
}
```

But the compiler shows an error on the line with mov "improper operand type". What is wrong and how can i fix it?

Comment: Is your app by any chance 64-bit?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Nope

Comment: You have some missing semicolons... Also, why do you need assembly? Why not intrinsics?

Comment: Why are you using `new` here?

Comment: @Cameron Yeah, but that's not the copypasted code,i wrote it "by hand" here, so all of the semicolons are in place in my code.

Comment: @MooingDuck Because I've found somewhere that a pointer to the char  array should be used in assembly, so i tried this, but it didn't help. And should it matter how i create the array?

Comment: _"I've found somewhere that a pointer to the char array should be used in assembly"_. Huh? There's no need for assembly in order to use pointers.

Comment: @Michael I meant that if i want to use an array in assembly, i should have a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char* s` is a local variable. It will be created when the function is called and "forgotten" when the function returns. There exists no "offset" (i.e an absolute memory address) for it at compiletime. But you can inline-assembler force to load the pointer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
   char* s;
   s=new char[80];
   __asm
   {
        mov ebx, s                  ; = mov ebx, [ebp-4]
        mov byte ptr [ebx], 'H'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+1], 'e'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+2], 'l'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+3], 'l'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+4], 'o'
        mov byte ptr [ebx+5], 0     ; Don't forget the terminator!
   }

    cout << s << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That cleared up a little. But what if i want to copy a string to another one element at a time? I tried this:

mov eax, s
mov ebx, d
mov byte ptr[ebx], al

But when my source string contains only numbers, some random characters get into my destination string.

Comment: Damn stackoverflow and no code formatting in comments. I hope you understood what i meant

Comment: Okay, i understood it myself. Thank you very much, everything works  now